# How do I activate my Vi sim in UAE?

Tags: indian-citizens, cellphones, uae, roaming, phone-networks

I moved to UAE 45 days ago and i missed on activating the roaming pack on my Indian sim card. Though i would do a online recharge when in UAE, but now i see there is no network and iam not sure if i recharge now my sim would be activated or not? Need your suggestions.

Comment: What did your SIM supplier say when you asked them?

Comment: If you're living long-term in the UAE, why not get an Emirati SIM card?

Comment: I don't have VI but JIO and for activating roaming only thing that helped was to get the sim somehow back to India and activate roaming there.. In case anyone around you or inn your circles is travelling back you can try asking them to take it back with them and activating the roaming there..